# Change textarea to HTML WYSIWYG Raptor Editor

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, editor, wysiwyg

I am trying to embed a HTML WYSIWYG [Raptor Editor](https://www.raptor-editor.com/) on a website. On the Raptor site, the [directions](https://www.raptor-editor.com/documentation/tutorials/basic-integration) say to just add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/raptor.min.js"></script>

<div class="raptor-editable">
    <p>
        Raptor may be integrated into a site many ways. 
        This article aims to cover the simplest integration possible.
    </p>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.raptor-editable').raptor();
    });
</script>
```

This code is supposed to allow users to edit any element on a page with the editor.

I created a textarea:

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

When I add the following JavaScript code, the textarea changes size, so I assume the code is doing something, however, I can't get an editor with toolbars and buttons to show up:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#editor').raptor();
    });
</script>
```

How can I get the editor to show up? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to just target that element using jQuery by changing your code to `$('#editor').raptor();`?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had another CSS file that was conflicting with the Raptor Editor code.

If you face a similar issue, I would suggest removing or disabling other CSS and JS dependencies to see if a different file has code that is overriding the Raptor code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#editor').raptor();
});
</script>
```

All the ".raptor();" does is initialize the element with the raptor api.

You can also pass in an object to .raptor({plugins:[]}) to add raptor plugins (https://www.raptor-editor.com/documentation/tutorials/plugins).

You may also need to add some presets

https://www.raptor-editor.com/demo/presets

Comment: This code changes the size of my textarea, so I guess it is doing something. I still however can't get an editor with toolbars and buttons to show up.

Comment: @TotZam you may need to initialize the raptor toolbar as well (i dont see why they would do that initially). 

You can read more at https://www.raptor-editor.com/documentation/tutorials/raptor-configuration-options-overview

Here is a demo on how to set the toolbar to inline https://www.raptor-editor.com/demo/presets

Comment: @TotZam also see https://www.raptor-editor.com/demo/presets for presetting the toolbar to be inline with the textbox